# TLD / Permanent 301 Redirect & Search Console, Not showing links - Links to Your Site

Tags: google-search-console, redirects

I did not get any answer in the webmaster forums so Im trying my luck here. 
So I got 4 TDLs that was redirected to a single new TLD.
Some of the pages where redirected to corresponding pages on the new domain and those not having anything corresponding where redirected to the home page.

Its been over 3 weeks since the redirects where done and I still can't see any of the old links in Search Console under "Links to Your Site" in the new property.

The new websites property was added to Search console way before the redirects where conducted. The structure of the new domain is https://www.example.com/en/home/
(but the property that Im using in search console is the root https://www.example.com)

Questions

1. If Googles search console does not show the old links does this mean that the links are not currently counted as backlinks and therefore does not add any ranks from the old domains? Or has google not yet found them?
2. Does "links to your site" report also understand & show links with 301? (i've tested the old URLs and almost 99% only have 1 redirect loop). So nothing wrong with the redirects. Done server-side.

A bite more about how i've redirected:

The old TLDs that got redirected are now being redirected to the different language folders on the new TLD: com/en/home/ etc.

3. Should I also include properties for every language folders? Or just keep com/

com/en/home/
com/de/home/
com/it/home/

Comment: 301 isn't a link, It's a redirect... therefore it won't display in links.

Comment: I well know that. But it should be displayed there. I've completed redirect for other sites before and they've showed up in the "links to your site" report. (I can confirm this, I looked into other site properties).

Comment: At any rate, if you are expecting Google to notice your changes and up date Search Console in 3 weeks, you are betting against the odds.

Answer (score 2):

Google Search Console (Link to your site report) is not up to date and has not enough accuracy.

So you should not count it.There are many backlinks that Google not display in "Link to your site" segment and there are many removed links that you can still see in "Link to your site" segment.

You can use other services such as Ahrefs and... to collect more data and more accuracy about your backlinks.